# Does it make sense to use FRP (reactive-banana in particular) for a turn based ascii game?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp

I'm thinking of something like [gnugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnugo)'s ascii interface. I'd think of the turns as a pair of co-evolving (monadic to allow for user input) streams. This reminds me vaguely of conduits.

I'm not really sure how I'd go about using existing libraries to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find the [operational](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational) package more useful for this.

In particular, have a look at the [TicTacToe.hs example](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/operational/blob/master/doc/examples/TicTacToe.hs).

Answer (score 3):

Probably not that much. The killer feature of FRP is modelling continuous time based events - great for GUIs but probably overkill for an ASCII turn-based game.